# How to print stdClass Object

Tags: php, stdclass

I need some help.

I have the variable $result.
If I print it, I will have:

```
echo "<PRE>";print_r($result);


stdClass Object
(
    [return] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [field1] => value1
                    [field2] => value2
                    [field3] => value3
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [field1] => value1
                    [field2] => value2
                    [field3] => value3
                )
            etc...
```

I need to use a foreach in order to print field by field, for example:

```
foreach ($result as $key)
    echo $key->field1;
```

But it doesnt work...

How I can do this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: `foreach ($result->return`

Comment: Turn the object into an array by casting it.`$result = (array) $result; print_r($result);`

Comment: Object 1:
The field 1 is "field1",
The field 2 is "field2",
The field 3 is "field3"
Object 2:
etc..

Comment: just cast to array: use  (array)$result

Comment: and then? inside the foreach?